# job generator jenkins plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am currently working on a project where we use jenkins to automate jobs and process continuous integration. We use a job Generator to produce jobs, that will run tests on the specified branch as generator parameter.

I would like to add some build step to the job generator, to be processed while it is run, and not copied to the newly created job. Is there a way to do that ?

A workaround would be to create a job that will do the task i want to do and then run the job generator, but it looks ugly to me. Any other way ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your additional step as a separate job and then use Multijob project to split the job and the generator into different phases, which will be processed sequentially. So first goes your 'additional step job', then job generations.